# Parse.com rest api login using vba returns "missing username"

Tags: excel, vba, rest, parse-platform

I am trying to authenticate Excel/VBA using the Parse.com rest api but so far I've spent several hours with no luck.

So far I have encoded my username and password using this function:

```
Public Function encodeURL(ByVal queryPart As String)
    Dim c As String
    While Len(queryPart) > 0
        c = Left(queryPart, 1)
        queryPart = Mid(queryPart, 2, Len(queryPart) - 1)
        If c Like "[A-Za-z0-9._~-]" Then
            encodeURL = encodeURL & c
        ElseIf c = " " Then
            encodeURL = encodeURL & "+"
        Else
            encodeURL = encodeURL & "%" & Right("0" & Hex(Asc(c)), 2)
        End If
    Wend
End Function
```

And the login Sub I wrote is as following:

```
Sub ParseLogin()

user = encodeURL(Range("A1").Value)
password = encodeURL(Range("A2").Value)
TargetURL = "https://api.parse.com/1/login/?user&password"
Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
HTTPReq.Open "GET", TargetURL, False
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "X-Parse-Application-Id", "MY_ID"
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "MY_KEY"
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
HTTPReq.send
MsgBox (HTTPReq.ResponseText)
End Sub
```

All I keep getting in return is:

{"code":200,"error":"missing username"}

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you should be using `https://api.parse.com/1/login?username=yourUserNameHere&password=yourPasswordHere`

Comment: @TimWilliams I must've done something wrong trying this earlier on tonight but it works not! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Williams sent me on the right track. 
For everyone with this problem. in the future The working code is:

```
Sub ParseLogin()
TargetURL = "https://api.parse.com/1/login?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD"
Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
HTTPReq.Open "GET", TargetURL, False
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "X-Parse-Application-Id", "MY_ID"
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "MY_KEY"
HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
HTTPReq.send
Range("A7").Value = HTTPReq.ResponseText
End Sub
```